# Changing links by priority - PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, href

I am currently working on a school project and appreciate your help.

HTML Code:

```
<a href="change-1.php">LINK 1</a>
<a href="change-2.php">LINK 2</a>
<a href="change-3.php">LINK 3</a>
```

Now as I am relatively new to PHP, I need clue wehere to start or which topics are relevant for my solution. I have already searched the Forum here and with google, but unforutenly, didn't find anything, that fits my needs.

What I need, is a PHP-Code, that contains 6 href Links and every Link has a priority. So every time somebody clicks on "LINK 1" on the html file, he gets directed to the PHP-File "change-1.php", where one of the six href Links get activated.

PHP CODE "change-1.php":

```
<?php 

if (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-1.com";
}
elseif (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-2.com";
}
elseif (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-3.com";
}
elseif (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-4.com";
}
elseif (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-5.com";
}
elseif (condition) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-6.com";
}

?>
```

Comment: So, do you mean every time `change-1.php` is visited, it will redirect to different URL based on some "conditions"? Where did you stuck?

Comment: You have a pretty good structure set up already :) What sort of condition are you trying to showcase the links on? Is it random which link would be displayed (with weightings for each)? Also, are you attempting to **automatically** redirect the user, or they would have to click on one of these links after clicking to visit `change-1.php`?

Comment: You could use mod-rewrite (if apache) for `^/change-[0-9]+\.php$`.

Comment: You could use the `?var=x` parameter method, and then retrieve it though a GET array.

Comment: @chris85 Sure but wouldn't they'd still have to use ^ ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- They are sending to different domains, not specific pages (or as the code currently is written). I had the same initial thought.

Comment: @Obsidian Age thanks for your reply :)  The redirect should be automatically and there should be weightings for each link.

Comment: @chris85 so use a header with my method.

Comment: `?var=x` in `href` and use a header/exit; that works. Now the ball's in your court @MarkK. you can build this ;-) after all, it is "your" homework. I gave you the building blocks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, `change-1.php` doesn't go to `http://www.someotherwebsite-1.com` necessarily.

Comment: Is it possible to use a click counter for each Website on the PHP File. If yes, which PHP Function I have to look for?

Comment: ......... that ^ makes this too broad now. You need to keep Googling this, with what I have already given you @MarkK.

Comment: @chris85 Nope..

Comment: @MarkK. Sure, just add a method before the header. Find one that either writes to a file/separate files, or use a database with an `UPDATE table SET counter=counter +1 WHERE x=y` type of thing.

Comment: Ok thank you guys for opening my mind a litte bit :) I think I found a way. I will use an array and the function mt_rand. Thats simple :D Thought too complex about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this should help

```
<a href="change.php?change=1">LINK 1</a>
<a href="change.php?change=2">LINK 2</a>
<a href="change.php?change=3">LINK 3</a>
```

Just create one `change.php` file

```
//to get change

<?php 

if ($_GET['change'] == 1) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-1.com";
}
elseif ($_GET['change'] == 2) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-2.com";
}
elseif ($_GET['change'] == 3) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-3.com";
}
elseif ($_GET['change'] == 4) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-4.com";
}
elseif ($_GET['change'] == 5) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-5.com";
}
elseif ($_GET['change'] == 6) {
    echo "http://www.someotherwebsite-6.com";
}

?>
```

Now this is the basic idea. You can manipulate the data however you want.

I hope you got the concept.